# Moments of the Hotelling Lawley Trace under the alternative

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, manova, hotelling-t2

The Hotelling Lawley trace is used in multivariate ANOVA, or for tests of the Multivariate General Linear Hypothesis (regression coefficient testing in many-to-many linear regression). For our purposes just say that $H, E$ are independent comformable Wishart random variables, and while $E$ is a central Wishart, $H$ may be non-central; the HLT is then defined as
$$
T = \operatorname{trace}\left(E^{-1} H\right).
$$

I would like to compute the first few (up to four if possible) moments of $T$ under the null and the alternative.  I am guessing that somehow Zonal Polynomials might be useful because $T$ is a symmetric function of the eigenvalues of $E^{-1}H$, but do not see the way forward.

Other hints: [Muller](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3721183/), citing [Pillai](https://repository.lib.ncsu.edu/bitstream/handle/1840.4/2164/ISMS_1954_88.pdf?sequence=1), gives the first two moments under the null ($H$ is central Wishart). It is hard to parse Pillai's manuscript, but some form of answer may be there.

Comment: Your title sounds like a romance novel: *Moments of the Hotelling Lawley Trace Under the Alternative*.